# Setting upper limit on font size

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a responsive site but I realized that some of my words are too big to be on the mobile screen. As a result, the screen becomes over 100% wide and thus becomes scrollable and loses its artistic touch.

How can I avoid this? how can I know what font would make my title word span past the mobile view? What are the best practices?

Comment: css media queries - if you Google there are lots and lots or resources

Comment: If the words are too long for the screen size its intended to be used on, then the design is flawed. Having said that, you still need to bear in mind edge cases that might make the site scroll-able. Can you post a code example as there could be a few things making this happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try flowtype.js http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/
this will help you in having a flexible font size accross different platform/device sizes. you can also set minimum and maximum size for your font

Comment: Adding javascript to make it responsive? Is that a good idea?

Comment: i think yes, if it works flawlessly in all browsers/devices

Comment: But it's still dependant on javascript. I guess pretty much everyone has it enabled these days. Don't really know what the real definition of being "responsive design" means, if javascript is allowed. I will probably take a look at that javascript myself later on. Seems interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have to set up some @media screen rules;

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {}
```

Then you can specify the base font size for specific widths. So for each media screen, set up fonts like;

```
html{font-size: x pt;}
```

And then you can control the specific font-sizes in different elements by adding `font-size:x rem;`

I think this is how pretty much all web devs does it. It's almost impossible to avoid `media screen` without getting a "not optimal" result.

Also, don't forget the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` inside your html.

Comment: do you mean it is impossible to avoid media screen to get desired result?

Comment: @pratikwebdev I added "almost" for a reason ;) . It really depends on what content you have on your website. If you want a fully responsive website that works for ALL devices and looks great with a lot of texts here and there, then you probably have no choice but to use media queries. If you ever find a website that is 100% responsive without media queries, post it to me. I want to see how they solve it otherwise ;)

Comment: No no your answer is great. I was little confused with that statement hence cleared it up. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try `word-break: break-all;`for the particular widget. This will allow line break in between a single word.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to avoid the scrollable content you have to set `max-width=100%` so the content does not get out of its container.

Now in order to accomplish nice results for your font-sizes you can use the unit `em` and not `px`. You can easily find a em->px converter. Also read this excellent article regarding your problem.

https://css-tricks.com/css-font-size/